# Pythonic way of storing Enums

Tags: python, enums

I have an Enum class Station.
(I'm using aenum, a library that "extends" python enum, and allows to use enums that have both an integer and a string)
This class Station) stores constants, with number and string representation. All fine.

Now, I want to store constant lists of Station objects. What I'm doing works but feels wrong. (I'm kind of new to python / programing.) Does someone have an advice on that ?
thank you.

Here is my code :

```
from typing import List
from aenum import Enum
from abc import ABC


class Station(Enum):
    _init_ = 'value string'

    BASTILLE = 3, 'Bastille'
    LEDRU = 1, 'Ledru Rollin'
    REPU = 10, 'République'
    CHATELET = 2, 'Châtelet les Halles'
    OURCQ = 5, 'Ourcq'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.string

    @property
    def nb(self):
        return self.value


class StationEnsemble(ABC):
    name :str
    stations : List[Station]

    @property
    def station_nbs_list(self):
        return [st.nb for st in self.stations]


class RecentStations(StationEnsemble):
    stations = [Station.OURCQ,Station.LEDRU,Station.CHATELET]

class EastStations(StationEnsemble):
    stations=[Station.BASTILLE,Station.OURCQ,Station.CHATELET]
```

Comment: If it works, you should probably post it at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This SE site is intended to provide extensive reviews of working code.

Comment: Why does it feel wrong?

Comment: @mkrieger1 : Creating  multiple classes that only store one list seems overkill, but I have little experience so perhaps it s normal

Comment: Why did you create those classes instead of just defining "constant" lists `RECENT_STATIONS = [Station.OURCQ, Station.LEDRU, Station.CHATELET]` etc.?

Comment: Because I need to process those list a bit with methods like station_nbs_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using several classes for your lists seems awkward. Why not just write a single class and make the specific lists its instances? This would make the `property` work (since it needs to be looked up on an instance) also give you a chance to fill in the `name` attribute you type hinted but never initialized.

```
class StationEnsemble:
    def __init__(self, name: str, stations: List[Station]):
        self.name = name
        self.stations = stations

    @property
    def station_nbs_list(self):
        return [st.nb for st in self.stations]

RecentStations = StationsEnsemble("recent", [Station.OURCQ, Station.LEDRU, Station.CHATELET])
EastStations = StationsEnsemble("east", [Station.BASTILLE, Station.OURCQ, Station.CHATELET])
```